# Combining Google Cloud Endpoint and Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

I have two things. A backend running on App Engine and a Android app. These needs to communicate in a efficient way.

What I already did. I created a api with Google Cloud Endpoints. This endpoint exposes calls. The objects in the backend are mapped to json and mapped back to objects in the Android app. This is what the Endpoints provide.

Sometimes I want to push information from the backend to the Android app. What I do now is I send a Google Cloud Message (GCM) to the Android app and these is updating everything by calling something on the Endpoint of the backend.

This situation is working without problems but it has some drawbacks:

- When I update a lot of devices at ones (what is happening a lot in my application) all those devices make a call to the backend and creating a large peak load.
- The extra call is using additional battery on the phones.

What I want is to add the updated information into the GCM. GCM has support to add 4kB of data. Large enough to add the json with the updated information. If I want to send more then 4kB I can always use the old situation.

So, basicly what I want is the following:

- When I'm going to send a GCM I retrieve the the correct objects from datastore/database.
- Those objects needs to be converted to json in the same way as the Endpoint library does.
- The json should be added to the GCM.
- In the Android application the json should be convert back to objects in the same way as the Endpoint library does.
- Continue processing those object the same way as before.

I found a [thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=216) that suggested that I should the gson library to do this. But I have problems in both backend and Android app. And also the json itself is not the same. I want to use the Endpoint library to serialize the same json and to deserialize to the same result as a Endpoint call.

Does anybody have any idea how to do that? Maybe a example or tutorial?

Comment: Do you need the Android clients to invoke the Endpoints API immediately on receiving the GCM Notification? If not, you could space out the requests from the clients (in a random fashion but across a threshold period say 30-60 mins) to avoid the peak.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Romin, but that's not a option. My app is a game with a lot of phones. All phones need to have the update as soon as possible. An average game is about a few hours. So updating over that kind of timespan is not a option. But thanks for the suggestion anyway.